# Facebook API - Can I filter a groups posts by a search keyword, as you can do on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to use Facebook's API to filter posts using the /feed edge. The example below shows how it is done using Facebook's website, but would like to know if there was a way to achieve this using their Graph API?

When using GET using Graph Explorer, I can easily see a list of the posts by using the /group_id/feed.

[image: Showing the search filter on Facebook's own website]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Graph API does not allow that kind of filtering right now, so it is not possible. You can only use the feed endpoint to get ALL entries, cache them in a database and filter on your own.